# How to parse the JSON data from PHP to JS with Mysql?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I have a JS that generate automatically the select html tag and cascade the 3 dropdowns. Now, I'm trying to get the data of the dropdowns will be filled thru Mysql database with json_encode but I have no luck.

How to parse the`json_encode` properly from PHP to JS to fill the dropdown automatically with Mysql?

Please help me.

**PHP:**

```
$result_region = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT DISTINCT state, city, avenue FROM tablename', OBJECT);
foreach($output as $rows){
$data[] = array('state'=> $rows->state, 'city' => $rows->city,'avenue'=> $rows->avenue);
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Working example of manually encoded data [JS](https://plnkr.co/edit/6mV3IFc9azanBzMiR0la?p=preview):

```
var data = getData();

var container = document.querySelector("#sl_form");

// initialize select-boxes with data
initSelect(data);

// reads the data and creates the DOM elements (select-boxes and their relevant options)
function initSelect(data) {
  var p, select, option, input, filteredOptions;
  for (var key in data) {
    p = document.createElement("p");
    p.innerHTML = key;
    select = document.createElement("select");
    select.name = key;
    container.appendChild(p);
    container.appendChild(select);
    filteredOptions = optionFilter(data[key].availableOptions, data[data[key].parent], data[key]);
    input = document.querySelector('select[name="' + key + '"');
    input.setAttribute("onchange", "updateSelect(this)");
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredOptions.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = filteredOptions[i].value;
      option.innerHTML = filteredOptions[i].value;
      input.appendChild(option);
    }
    input.options.selectedIndex = getSelectedIndex(filteredOptions, data[key]);
    input.setAttribute('model', data[key].selectedOption.value);
  }
}


// this function will be called on change of select-box
function updateSelect(element) {
  var input, option;
  setSelectedOption(element);
  for (var key in data) {
    filteredOptions = optionFilter(data[key].availableOptions, data[data[key].parent], data[key]);
    input = document.querySelector('select[name="' + key + '"');
    while (input.firstChild) {
      input.removeChild(input.firstChild);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < filteredOptions.length; i++) {
      option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = filteredOptions[i].value;
      option.innerHTML = filteredOptions[i].value;
      input.appendChild(option);
    }
    input.options.selectedIndex = getSelectedIndex(filteredOptions, data[key]);
    input.setAttribute('model', data[key].selectedOption.value);
  }
}

// set the selected-option of select-box when it's changed
function setSelectedOption(element) {
  var inputName = element.getAttribute("name");
  var inputValue = getSelectedText(element);
  var inputItem = data[inputName];
  var selectedOption, filteredOptions;

  // setting selected option of changed select-box
  for (var i = 0; i < inputItem.availableOptions.length; i++) {
    if (inputValue === inputItem.availableOptions[i].value) {
      inputItem.selectedOption = inputItem.availableOptions[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  // setting child object selected option now
  for (var key in data) {
    if (data[key].parent === inputName) {
      filteredOptions = optionFilter(data[key].availableOptions, data[data[key].parent], data[key]);
      data[key].selectedOption = filteredOptions[0];
    }
  }
}

// get the text of select-box
function getSelectedText(element) {
  if (element.selectedIndex == -1) {
    return null;
  }
  return element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
}

function getSelectedIndex(options, self) {
  var index;
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (self.selectedOption.value === options[i].value) {
      index = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  return index;
}

// get filtered options based on parent's selected value
function optionFilter(items, parent, self) {
  var result = [];
  if (typeof parent !== "undefined") {
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (typeof parent.selectedOption !== "undefined") {
        if (parent.selectedOption !== null && items[i].parentValue === parent.selectedOption.value) {
          result.push(items[i]);
        }
      }
    }
    if (typeof self.selectedOption === "undefined") {
      self.selectedOption = null;
    }
    if (self.selectedOption === null) {
      self.selectedOption = result[0];
    }
    return result;
  } else {
    return items;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't just echo multiple json_encodes one after the other, that will produce invalid json. Put together the full array you want to encode, then encode it once.

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't work

Comment: @scottevans93 it's working now

Comment: You `<select>` is still empty on the Fiddle.

Comment: no it's not. please click the link again.

Comment: Is it right? No idea. We don't know what your output needs to be.

Comment: @JonStirling, my updated PHP code still displayed only single row

Comment: @User014019 Yeah because you keep overwriting the keys in `$data` instead of assigning them to a new array item.

Comment: This is another great use case for the `datalist` element over select/options approach.

Comment: @Anthony But how? I'm still newbie in PHP json with JS

Answer (score 0):

Change your foreach loop as below. It will return all value. You were overriding values in foreach loop.

```
foreach($result_region as $row){
    $data[] = ['sl_region'=> $row->sl_region,
              'sl_city' => $row->sl_city,'sl_mall'=> $row->sl_mall];
}
```

if your php version is lower then 5.4 then use

```
foreach($result_region as $row){
    $data[] = array('sl_region'=> $row->sl_region,
              'sl_city' => $row->sl_city,'sl_mall'=> $row->sl_mall);
}
```

Comment: That probably means you're on < PHP 5.4 so you'll need to use the standard `array()` syntax instead of short array syntax (i.e. `[]`).

Comment: I see. But how can I call that JSON in JS? I only have a manually encoded json, https://plnkr.co/edit/6mV3IFc9azanBzMiR0la?p=preview

Comment: i don't think so your query will produce data like `get_data()`

Comment: if i have a query like that, how can I call it in JS?

Comment: make an ajax call